# Cleanup google calendar events by ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a beginner to "Apps Script"
I'm trying to automate adding project milestones from google spreadsheet to google calendar. I developed the following code. However I want to be able  to delete these events whenever the sheet gets updated.

First thought was to store the event ID once created in the sheet or somewhere and then use some script to delete. So a little help here could save me some time.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  let milestones = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("milestones").getValues();
milestones.forEach(function(e){
  if(!e[3]){
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(
      e[0],
      new Date(e[1]),
      new Date(e[2]),
      //    new Date('August 1, 2023'),
    //new Date('August 2, 2023'),
)}

var event_id = event.getId();
const event_1 = CalendarApp.getEventById(event_id);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
event_1.deleteEvent();
});
}
```

Note that in the code I experimentally tested delete the event after creation using the ID. What I want to do is for example add the event IDs to some new sheet and create a script with the 2nd part of the code to delete list of event IDs

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `What I want to do is for example add the event IDs to some new sheet and create a script with the 2nd part of the code to delete list of event IDs`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, what is `the 2nd part of the code`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.